# Что означает, если процесс потребляет > 100% процессора в linux?

Tags: linux, cpu, top

Когда у меня сервера подвергаются большой нагрузке, CPU в htop показывается > 100%.
Но я до конца не знаю, что это конкретно значит. Значит ли это, что используется больше 1 ядра или что не хватает мощности?
Просто как видно по нагрузке ядер в самом вверху htop, все ядра даже наполовину не нагружены, так почему показывает > 100%?

[image: htop]

Comment: Это значит что процесс поддерживает многопоточность и утилизирует более 100% одного потока, при этом эти проценты утилизации могут быть по 10 для каждого ядра/потока.

Comment: @PotroNik спасибо за ответ. а что означает "утилизирует"? вы сказали "до 10" правильно ли я понял, что максимум может быть 1000%?

Comment: Утилизирует в данном случае это использует. Все зависит от возможности приложения и в некоторых случаях приложение может использовать все потоки и ядра процессора, в вашем случае - это 1200%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В linux потребление процессорного времени считается на ядро. К примеру, если у вас 8 ядер в процессоре - максимальное возможное потребление будет 800%.

Comment: А можно увидеть команду, при которой в htop будет показываться ~800% для одного процесса на 8-ми поточном микропроцессоре?

Comment: @Xintrea ну вот вам программа на C#: `for (int i = 0; i < Environment.ProcessorCount; i++) new Thread(() => { while (true) ; }).Start();`, как скомпилировать и запустить сами ищите

Comment: Это программа а не команда. Стандартными средствами Linux можно продемонстрировать 800% нагрузки?

Comment: @Xintrea вы правда думаете, что в ОС в стандартной поставке есть команда "загрузить процессор"?

Comment: @Xintrea скомпилируйте программу - получите команду

Comment: Ну конечно есть, вот например: "while true; do dd if=/dev/urandom count=10M bs=1 | xz -9 -T8 > /dev/null ; done". Но видимо это неудачный пример, потому что нагрузки в 800% в этом многопотоке увидеть невозможно. С вашей стороны я жду команду хотя бы для компиляции C#, так как инструменты разработки под инфраструктуру компании Microsoft несколько инородны в Linux, и их знают разработчики C#, коим я не являюсь.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, правда есть, `hackbench(8)`

Comment: @Xintrea это ввод-вывод, им вы ядро на 100% не нагрузите. Готовых команд можете не ждать, потому что мне лень.

Comment: Вот, нашел: "7z b" - дает настоящий многопоток, ~750% на восьмипоточном проце.

Comment: Там ввод-вывод не главное, главное опции xz на 8 потоков, архивирование в памяти происходит и 100% легко получается но не больше. Кстати, sysbench (не hackbanch) тоже создает 8 процессов на 100%, но не потоков. Так что только 7z выручает.